# Angular 5, import SVG file into component

Tags: angular5, typescript2.0

I have def.svg file, I want to import this file into my angular 5 component.
Is it possible to import it using angular-cli? If yes, How can I import it?
Or Is any other way exists in angular 5?

def.svg:

```
<svg class="carousel-svg-defs">
   <defs> 
    .....
   </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one for importing SVG and displaying it inline
https://github.com/arkon/ng-inline-svg

**Installation**

```
npm install --save ng-inline-svg
```

**Configuration**

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { InlineSVGModule } from 'ng-inline-svg';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, InlineSVGModule.forRoot()],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
class AppModule {}
```

**Usage**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <div class="my-icon" aria-label="My icon" [inlineSVG]="'/img/image.svg'"></div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {}
```